# Splitting skips half a content when splitting by @

Tags: java, android, regex, split

I have an android application that requests data from a text file. when I try to separate the data and initialize classes, I have serious trouble because half the data after splitting is missing. The code for the DataSource is:

```
indicators = new ArrayList<Indicator>();
    try {
        InputStream fileStream = getResources().openRawResource(
                            R.raw.indicators);
        int fileLen = fileStream.available();
        // Read the entire resource into a local byte buffer.
        byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[fileLen];
        fileStream.read(fileBuffer);
        fileStream.close();
        displayText = new String(fileBuffer);
        String[] counts = displayText.split("@");
        for(String i: counts) {
            String[] temps = i.split(";");
            indicators.add(new Indicator(temps[0],temps[1],temps[2]));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // exception handling
        }
    for(Indicator i: indicators) Log.v("indicator", i.toString());
```

and the code for the Indicator class can be found here:

```
    public class Indicator {
    private String name;
    private String isoCode;
    private String topic;

    public Indicator(String topic, String isoCode,String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isoCode = isoCode;
        this.topic = topic;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public String getIsoCode() {
        return this.isoCode;
    }
    public String getTopic() {
        return this.topic;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return (this.topic + "," + this.isoCode + "," + this.name);
    }
}
```

After doing this process the following log file comes up with a lot of content missing:

http://pastebin.com/1j5s1Z81

The file seems to be skipping every other entry and because of that, my entire software is messing up. The source file below is:

http://pastebin.com/eAzppMdb

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the size of "counts" array before you start parsing it?

Comment: Is there any reason that you are not reading file `line-by-line` as all of `@` were present at the end of line except very last line. Anyhow try using `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to split on new line.

Comment: The counts of array is also 244... When printing the indicators I get double that which means that somehow the Log is not working properly or there is some underlying software.

Comment: To quote the [`InputStream.available()` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()): "Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. *It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream*." (emphasis added)

Comment: While I accept the premise of Input stream and the problem it might provide. The problem is not with retrieving files. The problem starts when the string is being split from what I saw. I printed the retrieved text file with line by line. Works like a charm

Comment: @Gempio Did you solved the question. As I dont see anything wrong with your current code. Try for 3 or 4 lines first instead of whole file content and try to debug it, where and why going wrong.

Comment: I didn't either. I think that the split goes funky with the '@' splitting and creates additional rows where there shouldn't. I solved this by using a buffered reader instead of splitting this up and the results were great ideal. The application is working without fail now :)

Comment: @Gempio I think this is not because of `@` its giving you that problem beacause of `@\n` combination. Sometimes it was able to split and sometimes not. Anyhow if you solved this then post it as answer and by accpeting it close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to solve the issue by ammending the command. I found a way around this problem however by using the BufferedReader class that read the opened string in. This has seemed to solve the issue.